# Pass data from NPM module to application

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules

Noob question incoming so I do apologize in advance. Im trying to develop my first NPM package, its meant to be a few simple functions that when called, pass response data to the application.

Ive been using `npm link` to link the package to a vuejs application and it seems to be working partially. When I call the `getPublicData()` function in the `mounted()` section it  seems to work. The `console.log(response.data)` part in the function does work and show the data in browsers console, but Im also trying to assign the response data to an array on the application side, this is the part Im having trouble with.

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental, but with all the complexity of NPM packages I've used in the past, surely there must be a way to pass this response data to the application?

My Code:

**Index.js (NPM Module)**

```
var axios = require("axios") 
module.exports = {  

getPublicData (req, res) {
    axios.get(`http://192.168.0.17:5000/test`)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      res.send(response.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("error");
    });
   }

}
```

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
<script>
import dtapp from "dtapp-api" //Linked NPM module

export default {
data () {
    return {
      myData: [],
    }
}, 
methods: {

  },
  mounted() {
   this.myData = dtapp.getPublicData();
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getPublicData` function needs to return the data, so your application can use it. Currently it doesn't return anything.

Here's how you can do that:

```
getPublicData () {
    return axios.get(`http://192.168.0.17:5000/test`)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      return response.data
    })
}
```

This will return a promise, so in the application you can do:

```
mounted() {
   dtapp.getPublicData()
  .then(data => this.myData = data)
  .catch(err => console.log("Error occurred:", err))
}
```

Comment: Ill have to look more into promises, but thank you sir, this worked :)